# Large Select Field Options are limiting my Count Function

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services

I recently took over a position to administrate multiple databases and creating multiple reports.

The report I'm currently hacking apart from a previous employee was developed in MS Visual Studio. Trying to get a total count from the column  Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_TYPE to return a total based on the filter ='SOCIAL'.

The COUNT() is returning multiple errors in regards to GROUP BY. Is there a simpler way to apply the COUNT() function with all of these other SELECT(ed) Rows? Thanks in advance. Current Report code is listed below.

```
SELECT     Name.ID AS Expr2, Name.MEMBER_TYPE, Name.STATUS, Name.COMPANY, Demo_Chapter.CH_UNIVERSITY, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
                      Demo_Chapter.CH_INSTALLED_DATE, 101) AS ChInstlDate, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_INACTIVE_DATE, 101) AS ChInctvDate, 
                      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_SEC_INACTIVE_DATE, 101) AS ChSecDate, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_REINSTALLED_DATE, 101) 
                      AS ChReInstall, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_THIRD_INSTALL, 101) AS ThrdInstall, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_FOURTH_INSTALL, 
                      101) AS FrthInstall, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_TH_INACTIVE_DATE, 101) AS ThInctvDate, Demo_Chapter.CH_TH_INACTIVE_REASON, 
                      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_FR_INACTIVE_DATE, 101) AS FrInctvDate, Demo_Chapter.CH_FR_INACTIVE_REASON, 
                      Demo_Chapter.CH_CARNEGIE_BASIC, Demo_Chapter.CH_CARNEGIE_SS, Demo_Chapter.CH_CARNEGIE_UNDER, Demo_Chapter.CH_CARNEGIE_ENROLL, 
                      Demo_Chapter.CH_ATHL_CONF, Demo_Chapter.CH_UG_ENROLL, Demo_Chapter.CH_NUM_WMN_STUD, Demo_Chapter.CH_SEC_INACTIVE_REASON, 
                      Demo_Chapter.CH_INACTIVE_REASON, Demo_Chapter.CH_RECRUIT_TIME, Demo_Chapter.CH_TERMS, Demo_Academic.AA_CHAPTER_GPA, 
                      Demo_Academic.AA_TERM, Demo_Academic.AA_YEAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_DATE, 101) AS EvntDate, 
                      Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_TYPE
FROM         Name INNER JOIN
                      Demo_Chapter ON Name.ID = Demo_Chapter.ID INNER JOIN
                      Demo_Chapter_Events ON Name.ID = Demo_Chapter_Events.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Demo_Academic ON Name.ID = Demo_Academic.ID
WHERE     (Name.MEMBER_TYPE = 'CCHP') AND (Name.STATUS IN ('A', 'SUSP')) AND (Demo_Academic.AA_TERM = 'SPRING') AND (Demo_Academic.AA_YEAR = '1415') AND 
                      (Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-08-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102)) AND (Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_TYPE = 'SOCIAL')
```

Comment: mySQL or SQL server?

Comment: SQL, I believe as I'm working in MS Visual Studio. Thank you.

Comment: Sample expected results would help me here.. as I'm confused if you're summing for 'SOCIAL' do you need to have the ce_event_Type returned as it will always be 'SOCIAL' or are you expecting other values to be present with a 0 count for that id?

Answer (score 0):

Reformatted your code for my readability: used an inline view to get the count of ce_Event_Types and limited to just socials; moving all limiting criteria for that table to that inline view.

This approach eliminates problems with artificial count inflation stemming from carnality issues.

```
SELECT Name.ID AS Expr2
 , Name.MEMBER_TYPE
 , Name.STATUS
 , Name.COMPANY
 , Demo_Chapter.CH_UNIVERSITY
 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_INSTALLED_DATE, 101) AS ChInstlDate
 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_INACTIVE_DATE, 101) AS ChInctvDate
 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_SEC_INACTIVE_DATE, 101) AS ChSecDate
 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_REINSTALLED_DATE, 101) AS ChReInstall
 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_THIRD_INSTALL, 101) AS ThrdInstall
 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_FOURTH_INSTALL, 101) AS FrthInstall
 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_TH_INACTIVE_DATE, 101) AS ThInctvDate
 , Demo_Chapter.CH_TH_INACTIVE_REASON
 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter.CH_FR_INACTIVE_DATE, 101) AS FrInctvDate
 , Demo_Chapter.CH_FR_INACTIVE_REASON
 , Demo_Chapter.CH_CARNEGIE_BASIC
 , Demo_Chapter.CH_CARNEGIE_SS
 , Demo_Chapter.CH_CARNEGIE_UNDER
 , Demo_Chapter.CH_CARNEGIE_ENROLL
 , Demo_Chapter.CH_ATHL_CONF
 , Demo_Chapter.CH_UG_ENROLL
 , Demo_Chapter.CH_NUM_WMN_STUD
 , Demo_Chapter.CH_SEC_INACTIVE_REASON
 , Demo_Chapter.CH_INACTIVE_REASON
 , Demo_Chapter.CH_RECRUIT_TIME
 , Demo_Chapter.CH_TERMS
 , Demo_Academic.AA_CHAPTER_GPA
 , Demo_Academic.AA_TERM
 , Demo_Academic.AA_YEAR
 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_DATE, 101) AS EvntDate
 , DEC.CE_EVENT_TYPE
 , DEC.cnt
FROM Name 
INNER JOIN Demo_Chapter 
  ON Name.ID = Demo_Chapter.ID 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, count(CE_EVENT_TYPE) as cnt, CE_EVENT_TYPE
            FROM Demo_Chapter_Events 
            WHERE CE_EVENT_TYPE = 'SOCIAL'
              AND  Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_DATE BETWEEN 
                   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-08-01 00:00:00', 102) 
               AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102) 
            GROUP BY id, CE_EVENT_TYPE) DCE
   ON Name.ID = DCE.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Demo_Academic 
   ON Name.ID = Demo_Academic.ID
WHERE (Name.MEMBER_TYPE = 'CCHP') 
  AND (Name.STATUS IN ('A', 'SUSP')) 
  AND (Demo_Academic.AA_TERM = 'SPRING') 
  AND (Demo_Academic.AA_YEAR = '1415')
```

Comment: I'm trying to count the Demo_Chapter_Events.CE_EVENT_TYPE that equal 'SOCIAL' and to display them as a total amount for Name.Company so that there is a column displaying the total number of events of that type (SOCIAL) from a specific Name.Company. Does that make sense? Thank you for your response.

Comment: I think I need some sample data showing the problem as I believe the problem is that the joins are causing your counts to be artificially inflated.  Based on your query I think we can simply count the events before the join which negates the inflated records due to carnality.  I've taken a stab what what I think you want but I'm not sure.  (created inline view and moved limiting criteria to that inline view.)

Comment: Here is a screen shot. On the right where it repeats the word SOCIAL is where I'm trying to get a total number of that type of event. But the lines keep repeating for the specific Name.COMPANY. I'm looking for an INT total as one line of info related to the 'SOCIAL' for the Name.COMPANY. [link]http://imgur.com/OFy9hYv

Comment: I did update did the inline view provide the count next to ce_Event_Type as desired?

Comment: It pitches this error - Error in list of function arguments: 'FROM' not recognized.
Error in list of function arguments: ',' not recognized.
Error in list of function arguments: ')' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: bah had an extra ) and field alis for cnt in wrong place.